# Existing target has no 'swift compiler code generation' section

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, bridging-header

I have an existing Objective-C iOS project and I want to add swift files to it.
The project has 2 targets.

I created the bridging header MyProject-Bridging-Header.h file and the automatically created bridging header MyProject-Swift.h is generated by Xcode as expected. But only for target "A".

Target "B" doesn't see the MyProject-Swift.h file. The reason is, that the target doesn't have the 'swift compiler code generation' that is responsible for the automatic generation of this file.

I tried to set the file on in the project level - I expected I would be inherited to the targets. But this doesn't work.

How do I get he 'swift compiler code generation' into the existing targets build settings manually?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out by accident how to do it: create a new swift file and include all necessary targets (Xcode asks at the end of the file setup). Then Xcode asked me if I wanted the Bridging Header to be created and - much more important - added the Swift section to the target

Comment: Helpful! Note that, for this to work, you must first deselect the target for any existing Swift files.

Answer (score 12):

For any new users the setting you are looking for is under "swift compiler - general"

Just scroll down from swift compiler - code generation.
Also make sure you select "all" and not "basic" (at the top) basic hides some features.

Answer (score 2):

Building was an important step for me. Adding the Swift file to the target of interest, creating the bridging header, and **building the project with these files included**. It's not enough to just add it, then delete them and expect Xcode to update the project build settings for you.